# How to throw custom exceptions in NetBeans using PHPUnit

Tags: unit-testing, netbeans, exception, phpunit

I'm using NetBeans 7.0.1 and PHPUnit 3.6

During test run I can see nice PHPUnit Exceptions like http://gyazo.com/c74906300d121496ded410f81144fa4f

I want to throw my custom exception and see it in PHPUnit test session. In Output window it looks ugly.

Answer (score 1):

The text you see is simply a string that PHPUnit builds when creating the exception, and you can do it too.

```
throw new RuntimeException('Error on query: ' . $query);
```

Use `\n` and spaces to format your message how you like.